# bst file/bibliography: how to remove the space created after the volume number and before the comma?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

[image]

My code:

```
\bibliographystyle{nature_style}
\bibliography{bibliography_3}

    @Article{Holzhauser2013,
  author  = {Holzhauser, Carolin and Liebl, Renate and Goepferich, Achim and 
Wagenknecht, Hans-Achim and Breunig, Miriam},
  title   = {RNA “Traffic Lights”: An Analytical Tool to Monitor siRNA 
Integrity},
  journal = {ACS Chem. Biol.},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {8},
  pages   = {890-894},
}
```

Here my bst code:

```
% version = 1.09 of nature.bst 1999 July 26

% 1991 July 3  last name first 
%              bold face volume numbers
%              volume followed by comma, not colon
%              parenthesis around year
%              no comma after page numbers (not done yet!)
% 1991 Aug 7   Titles removed in FUNCTION {format.title}.
%              (Should put \nocite{TitlesOn}
%              mechanism in from jmb.bst next)
% 1991 Aug 29  in inproceedings, book title preceeds the editors!!
% 1991 Aug 30  year at end of inproceedings
%              no 'pages' in inproceedings
%              when no comma, don't put space instead
% 1992 Aug 18  no comma between note and date in unpublished references
% 1998 May 12  titles added BACK to format.title
% 1998 June 2  titles of books are not italic

% 1999 July 24 Now Nature *wants* titles of books to be italic!!!

% 1999 July 26: added comma in front of month

% from:
% BibTeX standard bibliography style `unsrt'
        % version 0.99a for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later, LaTeX version 2.09.
        % Copyright (C) 1985, all rights reserved.
        % Copying of this file is authorized only if either
        % (1) you make absolutely no changes to your copy, including name, or
        % (2) if you do make changes, you name it something other than
        % btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, and abbrv.bst.
        % This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.
        % The file btxbst.doc has the documentation for this style.

ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block
           docomma }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=

  #1 'docomma :=    % if it is 0 then don't do commas, otherwise do them.
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { % doing a comma is controlled specifically using docomma
      docomma #0 =
      { "" * write$ } % TDS nothing if no comma
      { ", " * write$ }
      if$
    }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
%   { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=  % TDS
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't := % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { ", editors" * }
        { ", editor" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ 
%title empty$
%    { "" }
%    { "" } % the zapped title the newly unzapped ...
%    { title "t" change.case$ } % TDS NO TITLES
%    { title "t" change.case$ } % TDS TITLES RETURNED
% if$
title % takes the titel from yout biliography as it is 
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
%        'year                       % TDS
%        { month " " * year * }      % TDS
         { " (" year * ")" * }
         { ", " month * " " * " (" year * ")" * * }
% 1999 July 26: added comma in front of month
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title
% 1998 June 2:  current Nature instructions say not to emph book title.
% emphasize
% 1999 July 24: NOW THEY WANT IT TO BE ITALICS!
emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " edition" * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " edition" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
%        { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
%        { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
% no word in nature!
        { "" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
%{ volume field.or.null TDS
{ "{ \textbf{ " volume " }}" * * field.or.null  % make volume bold face
  number empty$
    'skip$
    {                                   %"(" number * ")" * * for the case you need issue number
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
%        { ":" * pages n.dashify * } % TDS
        { ", " * pages n.dashify * } % comma, not colon TDS
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { "chapter" }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { "In " booktitle emphasize * }
%       { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
        { % book title preceeds the editors!! TDS
          "In "
          booktitle
          ", "
          *
          *
          format.editors
          *
          }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
%          emphasize  NO LONGER ITALIC
%zzz

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Technical Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
          warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { booktitle empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              ""
            }
            { "In {\em " booktitle * "\/}" * }
          if$
        }
        { "In " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF 
      format.vol.num.pages output  % these now do their own comma!!
      format.date "year" output.check
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  %note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF
  format.date "year" output.check
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
          publisher output
          format.date "year" output.check
        }
        {
%          new.sentence
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF
          " (" output.nonnull
          organization output
          publisher output
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
      address output.nonnull
% year is at the end TDS
%          format.date "year" output.check
          year ")" * output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output.nonnull
          address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        { address new.block.checka
          address output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { organization address new.block.checkb
      organization output
      address output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
        { publisher new.sentence.checka }
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
        }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      editor empty$
        'skip$
        { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
      #0 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS OFF
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
      #1 'docomma :=    % TURN COMMAS ON
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

READ

STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome, please remove the content of the bst file and provide a proper minimal working example instead.

Comment: All I need is a way to display my bibliography from my bib file with a proper punctuation and keep the capital letters in the title of the article if needed.

Comment: That file should not be used as it violates the copyright. Anyway, remove the space responsible from `{ "{ \textbf{ " volume " }}" * * field.or.null` to `{ "{ \textbf{ " volume "}}" * * field.or.null` (`{ "{ \textbf{ " volume "<noSpaceHere>}}" * * field.or.null`).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Maybe this is a "(" too much or too less.

Comment: Works for me, with a minimal example i just grabbed off the wikibook. You did not provide a minimal example for us to test. You only provided a screenshot.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your other questions I created the following MWE (please add always an simular MWE to your next questions, then it is easier to help you!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Schwechheimer2016,
  author       = "Schwechheimer, Christian and Merkel, Marcus
                  and Bohl{\"a}nder, Peggy R and Wagenknecht,
                  Hans-Achim",
  title        = "Synthetic Wavelength-Shifting Fluorescent
                  Probes of Nucleic Acids",
  pages        = "83-100",
  publisher    = "Springer",
  address      = "Cham",
  year         = "2016",
  editor       = "Nakatani, Kazuhiko and Tor, Yitzhak",
  volume       = "31",
  isbn         = "978-3-319-27111-8",
  booktitle    = "Modified Nucleic Acids",
  doi          = "10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4",
  url          = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4",
}
@Article{Holzhauser2013,
  author  = {Holzhauser, Carolin and Liebl, Renate and Goepferich, Achim 
             and Wagenknecht, Hans-Achim and Breunig, Miriam},
  title   = {RNA “Traffic Lights”: An Analytical Tool to Monitor 
             siRNA Integrity},
  journal = {ACS Chem. Biol.},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {8},
  pages   = {890-894},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrbook} 

\begin{document}

text \cite{Holzhauser2013} text \nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{mynature_style} % nature_style % to use changed bst file!
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use the created bib file by filecontents
\end{document}
```

Copy file `nature_style.bst` to `mynature_style.bst`.
After changing `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}` in file `mynature_style` as mentioned in a comment by @Johannes_B to:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
%{ volume field.or.null TDS
{ "{ \textbf{ " volume "}}" * * field.or.null  % make volume bold face
  number empty$
    'skip$
    {                                   %"(" number * ")" * * for the case you need issue number
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
%        { ":" * pages n.dashify * } % TDS
        { ", " * pages n.dashify * } % comma, not colon TDS
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

you will get the result you need.  But be sure you are allowed to use the file `nature_style.bst`.

The result is:

[image: resulting bibliography]